# How do i make a bot check if a message was sent in a certain server? (discord.py)

Tags: filter, discord, discord.py

Not much to it really.
I just have a bot which has a chat filter function which i only want to run on my friends server. However i have the bot in multiple servers. What do i put before the code to make it only run in a certain server?

Comment: Please show us your code so we have something to Start from :)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to just put a conditional in your `on_message` definition that prevents it from taking action if the message wasn't from the given server.

```
async def on_message(message):
    WHITELISTED_SERVER_ID = '01234567890123456789'
    if message.channel.server.id == WHITELISTED_SERVER_ID:
        // do whatever the bot does
```

You can adapt that to however your bot is designed. There are also other concerns (e.g. if the message is from a direct message, `message.channel.server` won't exist), but that's the gist of it.